# At Github Pages my website don't show photos

Tags: html, css, git, github

Here is link to my website https://rahul27103.github.io/CV/ it does not shows photo.I also shows you code and my repositery screenshoot.

[image: repositery screenshot]

You can check code in crome inspect tool on website.conact me https://rahul27103.github.io/CV/Contact%20Me.html for further detail and solution.I am new learner.

Comment: Image file name is case-sensitive. e.g FILE.jpg is not the same as FiLe.jpg. So make sure the photo name matches your  img src path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fie URIs from GitHub Pages are case-sensitive. In your HTML file, you referenced the file as

"Files for My personal website/Rahul **P**hoto.jpg

whereas in your repo, the file is stored as:

"Files for My personal website/Rahul **p**hoto.jpg"

Fix the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing much bigger problem, please check your photo/image filename:
you had mentioned in your GitHub. like, `<img  src="Files for My personal website/Rahul Photo.jpg"/>` , make the change as per your image filename,`<img src="Files for My personal website/Rahul photo.jpg"`>
you must sure with filename is case-sensitive.